# Using Generics to accomplish an HTML scraper. Right or Wrong?

Tags: c#, html, xml, generics, scraper

My requirement is to download and scrape various HTML pages, extracting lists of Objects from the code on the page depending on what object type we are looking for on that page. Eg one page might contain an embedded list of doctors surgeries, another might contain a list of primary trusts etc. I have to view the pages one by one and end up with lists of the appropriate object types.

The way I have chosen to do this is to have a Generic class called `HTMLParser<T> where T : IEntity, new()`

`IEntity` is the interface that all the object types that can be scraped will implement, though I haven't figured out yet what the interface members will be.

So you will effectively be able to say

```
HTMLParser<Surgery> parser = new HTMLParser<Surgery>(URL, XSD SCHEMA DOC);
IList<Surgery> results = parser.Parse();
```

`Parse()` will validate that the HTML string downloaded from the URL contains a block that conforms to the XSD document provided, then will somehow use this template to extract a `List<Surgery>` of Surgery objects, each one corresponding to an XML block in the HTML string.

The problems I have are

1. Im not sure how to specify the template for each object type in a nice way, other than `HTMLParser<Surgery> parser = new HTMLParser<Surgery>(new URI("...."), Surgery.Template);` which is a bit clunky. Can anyone suggest a better way using .NET 3.0/4.0?
2. Im not sure how in a Generic way I can take the HTML string, take an XSD or XML template document, and return a generic list of constructed objects of the Generic Type. Can anyone suggest on how to do this?
3. Finally, I'm not convinced generics are the right solution to this problem as it's starting to seem very convoluted. Would you agree with or condemn my choice of solution here and if not, what would you do instead?

Comment: While you are likely to want some higher-level classes, have you looked at the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)? This may do what you want out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not convinced that generics are the right solution, either. I implemented something very similar to this using good old inheritance, and I still think that's the right tool for the job.

Generics are useful when you want to perform the same operations on different types. Collections, for example, are a good example of where generics are very handy.

Inheritance, on the other hand, is useful when you want an object to inherit common functionality, but then extend and/or modify that functionality. Doing that with generics is messy.

My scraper base class looks something like this:

```
public class ScraperBase
{
    // Common methods for making web requests, etc.

    // When you want to download and scrape a page, you call this:
    public List<string> DownloadAndScrape(string url)
    {
        // make request and download page.
        // Then call Scrape ...
        return Scrape(pageText);
    }

    // And an abstract Scrape method that returns a List<string>
    // Inheritors implement this method.
    public abstract List<string> Scrape(string pageText);
}
```

There's some other stuff in there for logging, error reporting, etc., but that's the gist of it.

Now, let's say I have a Wordpress blog scraper:

```
public class WordpressBlogScraper : ScraperBase
{
    // just implement the Scrape method
    public override List<string> Scrape(string pageText)
    {
        // do Wordpress-specific parsing and return data.
    }
}
```

And I can do the same thing to write a Blogspot scraper, or a custom scraper for any page, site, or class of data.

I actually tried to do something similar, but rather than using inheritance I used a scraper callback function. Something like:

```
public delegate List<string> PageScraperDelegate(string pageText);

public class PageScraper
{
    public List<string> DownloadAndScrape(string url, PageScraperDelegate callback)
    {
        // download data to pageText;
        return callback(pageText);
    }
}
```

You can then write:

```
var myScraper = new PageScraper();
myScraper.DownloadAndScrape("http://example.com/index.html", ScrapeExample);

private List<string> ScrapeExample(string pageText)
{
    // do the scraping here and return a List<string>
}
```

That works reasonably well, and eliminates having to create a new class for every scraper type. However, I found that in my situation it was too limiting. I ended up needing a different class for almost every type of scraper, so I just went ahead and used inheritance.

Comment: +1: Considering how different input for each entity might get, I suppose inheritance with scrapper per entity sounds very reasonable. I  had something similar in mind, glad to see I'm not alone!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it does make more sense to do it that way, I was just trying to figure out how I could get a strongly typed collection back cleanly rather than say a collection of just textual strings, but it was not working out as planned. Regarding the actual parsing of the page, do you have any suggestions or tutorial links as to how I can use XSD templates to parse the HTML read in to create my collection? Eg if I want to specify a template that is for example

Comment: <sitenames><sitename name=?? id=?? />...etc for however many sitename tags there are, then end with </sitenames> and end up with a collection of SiteName objects, with the Name and Id properties populated..... is there a nice, clean easy way to do this or do I have to code it manually?

Answer (score 1):

I would rather focus on your parser/verifier classes, as designing them properly will be cruicial to the ease of future usage. I think it's more important **how** the mechanism will determine **which** parser/verifier to use basing on input.

Also, what happens when you're told you need to parse yet another type of website, say for `Invoice`entities - will you be able to extend your mechanism in 2 easy steps in order to handle such requirement?